# Feed imports don't seem to trigger

Tags: 8, feeds

The [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module is still in development for D8, but I'm trying to test it. I can set up Feed Types, but the actual imports do not seem to trigger.

Does anyone know how to do this on Drupal 8?

Comment: As you had it answered here - https://www.drupal.org/node/2604358#comment-10865318 - presumably this now needs deleting or answering over here for future ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1.** Go to Administration > Content > Feeds (http://www.example.com/admin/content/feed)
>
> **2.** Add a Feed (http://www.example.com/feed/add).
>
> source: https://www.drupal.org/node/2604358#comment-10865318